# MySQL tables of constants

Tags: php, sql, foreign-keys, constants

I'm just trying out foreign keys for the first time and I'm worried I'm getting a little carried away.

For several of my class variables and their corresponding database records, I've got sets of constants which limit the values that can be chosen.  These are currently set and validated using PHP.

What I'm wondering is, should I make tables of these constants in MySQL and lock them into foreign keys?  Is this worth the trouble, or is the PHP definitions enough?

---

For example, say I've got a table `transactions`, with PHP constants defined for `'credit'` and `'debit'`.

`transactions` has a `type` field which indicates whether the transaction was credit or debit.

Should I create another table (`transactions_constants` or something) that defines the constants used in `transactions(type)` and foreign-key them together?

Comment: I think creating a separate table is overkill.  You can make your `type` column an [enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) to help with limiting the allowed values

Comment: Ahh yes enum is what I was looking for! I had that funny feeling that I was doing something the hard way...thanks.  Can you post as an answer and I'll (probably) accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should. With FK:

- Your database has a more specific interface.
- The DB has a clear structure (a DB should be readable regardless of code).
- You can avoid accidents with inserts/updates by other DB clients (like PMA).

But you can also have copy of table with consts as consts in PHP (I use codegeneration for this).

Yes, you could use enum. But read [8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) first.

Comment: It's been a few days using this architecture and I have to say it's working out swimmingly.  Most everything in that article was spot-on.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, creating a separate table for the transaction type is probably overkill.  You can make your `type` column an [enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) to help with limiting the allowed values on the database side.

If transaction types had more data associated with them that you wanted to store in the database then a separate table and a foreign key relationship would be the way to go.

Comment: Sorry @User going to undo my accept and wait for a few more responses to see if there's any new light...I often accept too quick and then turns out a month later there's some new discussion that I missed :/

Answer (score 2):

If your values set change rarely, you should use [MySQL ENUM datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html), and you should turn on MySQL restrict mode. For example:

If your table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    type enum('credit','debit') not null,
);
```

the strict mode will help you when you execute a query like

```
update table `table` set `type` = 'credit1 ' where id = 2
# strict mode on: an error will be raised
# strict mode off: `type` will be '' (empty string)
```

The above query can not be run if your code is perfect. It's up to you.